# How can I make an Http GET request for this json on android?

Tags: java, android, http, server, get

[{
  "name":"George",
  "id":"2222",
  "lastname":"wist",
  "date":"07/08/07"
},
{
  "name":"aaron",
  "id":"1111",
  "lastname":"borris",
  "date":"06/06/09"
}]

Comment: Use `HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp, or some other HTTP client library to make a `GET` request of some server containing that JSON.

Comment: do you have a specific problem with the common methods found by searching for basic keywords in your favorite search engine?

Comment: You can use Volley library.

Comment: can you post your API url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Volley` library. Android volley is a networking library was introduced to make networking calls much easier, faster without writing tons of code.

To use `Volley`, you have to add below `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    .............
    ......................
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
}
```

**Here is your required HTTP request:**

```
/**
 * Method to make json array request where response starts with [
 * */
private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

    String url = "YOUR_API_URL";

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", response.toString());
                    // Here response is: 
                    // [{ "name":"George", "id":"2222", "lastname":"wist", "date":"07/08/07" }, { "name":"aaron", "id":"1111", "lastname":"borris", "date":"06/06/09" }]

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                            String name = person.getString("name");
                            String id = person.getString("id");
                            String lastname = phone.getString("lastname");
                            String date = phone.getString("date");

                            jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Id: " + id + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Lastname: " + lastname + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "Date: " + date + "\n\n\n";

                        }

                        Log.d("onResponse", "JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("onErrorResponse", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Here is a very nice tutorial about [Android JSON parsing using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Hope this will help~